# How to Access UI Elements Of a Class inherited from UI View in viewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, uielement

i Create a Class A inherited from UIView Class where am creating Labels, TextFields etc programmatically and want to access them within another viewController B.
I use the Property but its not working is there any way to access them not using tags or [isKindOfClass ] method. Any help will be appreciated Thanks !.

Answer (score 0):

The UIView class has a property called "subviews". It is an array and it holds all the subviews of a UIView.

If you wish to access them without iterating you have to create a custom UIView class and define your subviews as properties

Comment: I have a custom Class with properties inherited from UIView Class but not accessible in a viewController ... #Lubakis